# Is there a software that rezises similar images to overlap

Tags: software-recommendation, resize, image-editing

I was working on a graph theory presentation and I have a series of operations on the graphs that I am demonstrating, thus I have very small changes in the graphs, such as 1 node being deleted or various colors changing but the overall structure is exactly the same. The only problem is the images are all different sizes and I don't have the time to go through every image and resize it. Is there a software that can do this?

Example:
[image: Graph 1]

[image: Graph 2]

[image: Graph 3]

Comment: I believe one route would be to trim out all the whitespace and then batch resize them to all be the same width. I'm on mobile, but it seems to me like they may have varying amounts of whitespace on all sides right now. You could do it in like Photoshop or even ImageMagick

Comment: There are two problems. 1. The background canvas is not the same size, and 2. The graphics themselves are not the same size either.  It's going to be very hard to automate this, and to be honest ,by the time you have worked out a solution it might be easier to do it manually in software such as Photoshop or GIMP. Obviously I don't know your skill level in image editing so this may be impractical for you. Perhaps consider paying someone to do it for you?

Comment: I noticed that the last example image just randomly has bigger balls and text in comparison to the other two. You can't really perfectly align them unless it's in a vector format. Then you could resize all of the ballsies and text around their center point.... but even then it would make more sense to export them out all at the same size from the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Adobe Photoshop** has a feature called "auto-align layers" that can , as you might guess, automatically align layers.

Below I used this method:

1. I added your three example images to deliberately mismatched size canvases.
2. I imported these three images as layers in a new document.
3. I locked the "reference" layer.
4. Hit "Edit" > "Auto-Align Layers..."
5. I accepted the default settings, yo umight have even better results by adjusting them.

Below I varied the opacity of the top two layers, and you can see the alignment is really quite good. This could all of course be saved as an action, and run on a batch of files.

[image]

Comment: great tip! I didn't know that.

Comment: @theyve - I hardly remembered it myself haha, must be ten years since I used it. Solving problems here is a good way to brush up on seldom used functionality :)